# Excel formula to get time from distance and speed

Tags: excel, math

I need a formula to get Time from Distance (km) and Speed (kt)

```
A1 = 100km (distance)
A2 = 40knot (speed)
A3 = 00:00:00 (time) which I need!?
```

Does somebody know hot to get this? Thank you

```
UPDATE - Solved!
Knots should be first converted to km/h. So formula is =(100/(40*1,852))/24
```

Comment: maybe `=100/40/24` ?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I feel that something is missing...some constant maybe because =100/40/24 is 2:30:00 and it should be 1:21:00, according to https://www.timecalculator.net/speed-distance-time-calculator Do I need to convert knot in some other value?

Comment: OK I figure out formula is =(100/(40*1,852))/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Algebra:  Solve for time.  Since D = rt solve for t;  t = D/r.  in other words A3 = A1/A2.

Comment: To return a true time value you are going to have to divide again by the unit of time used in speed. e.g for km/hr, divide by 24.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, as I wrote in comment above =100/40/24 is 2:30:00 and it should be 1:21:00, according to timecalculator.net/speed-distance-time-calculator Do I need to convert knot in some other value?

Comment: OK I figure out formula is =(100/(40*1,852))/24